# Содержимое директории в ZIP Yii2 Advanced

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. Появилась проблема. Нужно запаковать файлы в ZIP-архив, файлы с определенной директории.

Почитал информацию, создал класс прямо как в примере:

```
public function createZip()
{
    $zip_name = 'adcs.zip';
    $zip = new \ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zip_name, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if ($handle = opendir('/maken')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !strstr($entry,'.php')) {
                $zip->addFile($entry);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

    $zip->close();
}
```

Но получаю в ответ `Class 'ZipArchive' not found`. Подозреваю, что нужно где-то подключить сам класс.

Так как, в итоге, мне запаковать содержимое файла?

P.S. PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы присутствовал класс ZipArchive, необходимо установить php-zip.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```